# How to create custom module to remove .html part from product page?

Tags: url

I want to create a custom module to remove .html part from product page. I have found solution only from admin panel but want editing in module. Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom module to remove .html from product page

By using below link reference -

https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-prevent-omit-category-path-from-product-url-to-access-the-product-page/